# Rust generic struct reader and writer

Tags: rust

I'm wondering if there is a good way to make a function that can read any type of struct from a file. I was able to write a file with the function below. This allows me to write any struct that implements Serialize. I'm trying to do something similar with a reader using generics and struct that impl Deserilize. However, I seem to be hitting issues on the generics and lifetimes. Is there a way to read files of any type of struct?

```rs
extern crate bincode;
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

fn main() {
    let filename = String::from("./prices.ruststruct");
    {
        let now = Instant::now();
        let (open_prices, close_prices) = gen_random_prices();
        let test_prices = TestPrices::new(open_prices, close_prices);
        write_struct(&filename, &test_prices);
        println!("{}", now.elapsed().as_micros());
    }
    {
        let test_prices = read_struct::<Prices>(&filename);
        let now = Instant::now();
        let total_prices: f64 = test_prices.open_price.iter().sum();
        println!("{}", now.elapsed().as_micros());
    } 
}


#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Prices {
    open_price: Vec<f64>,
    close_price: Vec<f64>,  
}

fn write_struct(filename: &str, data: &impl Serialize) {
    let filename = format!("{}.ruststruct", filename);
    let bytes: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&data).unwrap();
    let mut file = File::create(filename).unwrap();
    file.write_all(&bytes).unwrap();
}

fn read_struct<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(filename: &str) -> T {
    let filename = format!("{}.ruststruct", filename);
    let mut file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let mut buffer = Vec::<u8>::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    let decoded: T = bincode::deserialize(&buffer[..]).unwrap();
    decoded
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
fn read_struct<'a, T: Deserialize<'a>>(filename: &str) -> T {
```

`Deserialize<'a>` is only a suitable bound when you are planning to let the deserialized structures *borrow from the input data*. But this function cannot allow that, because it discards `buffer` when it returns.

For a structure like your `Prices`, [`T: DeserializeOwned`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html) will work. This guarantees that the structure *won't* borrow from the input data, so it's okay to drop the data.

If you want to allow borrowing then you must put reading the file into a buffer, and deserializing from the buffer, in separate functions so that the caller can keep the buffer alive as long as it wants to use the deserialized structure.